# How to best calculate speed travelled in kilometres per hour

Tags: c++, calculation

I've returned to C++ after a long absence from the programming language, currently I'm trying to complete my program by attempting to calculate speeds in kilometres. So far I've got my program to extract a series of data from a file e.g. lat and long coordinates, with times etc.

As a result of these processes, I've now got two arrays one is an array of integer values that correspond to minutes between each of my destinations, and one is a float array containing my distances between my destinations e.g.

```
float kilometres[4] = { 1.1, 0.2, 1.3, 0.4};

int minutes[4] = { 10, 3, 12, 6 };
```

I would now like to calculate and return values for how long it takes to travel for example 1.1 kilometres in 10 minutes, which should return 6.6 kilometres per hour. But I am a little unsure as to how this would be best achieved within C++ and any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. (I'm not Siri!) If you travel 1.1 kilometers in 10 minutes, your average speed is 1.1 / 10 * 60 = 6.6 kph, no? Why should it return 10.6?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry it should be 6.6 kph, it was a typo

Comment: You do it exactly the same as you do with pen and paper.

Comment: Divide a length with a duration and you get a speed in some unit. Multiply by a constant to get a new unit.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a math problem than a programming one, but I'll answer since it is a common thing to do when you code.

When you divide a distance with a duration, the result is a speed of some unit. The unit is determined by the units of distance and duration. So if you divide kilometers with minutes, you'll get kilometers per minute.

To convert a unit to another unit can in general be done by simply multiplying with some constant. If you want to change kilometer per minute to kilometers per second, then you divide by 60.

> Temperature units are an exception to when you can multiply by a factor only. Not because something intrinsic property of temperature. We just happened to choose a unit that allows for negative values. It is possible to do the same for all quantity. For instance you can define a velocity unit where 0m/s does NOT mean standing still. Highly impractical, but possible.